# DNSMasq swallows local A-entries

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

When I query the ISP's DNS server for `foo.example.com`, it comes back with something like this:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
foo.example.com. 159 IN A       192.168.40.20
```

(note that the IP address is a local one)

When I do the same over DNSMasq, the response is empty; the `A` record is missing. It works fine for every other address I've tried.

What is this, a mis-configuration of DNSMasq, a bug, or expected behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have dnsmasq's [rebind protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) enabled with [this option](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dnsmasq):

```
   --stop-dns-rebind
          Reject (and log) addresses from upstream nameservers  which  are
          in  the private IP ranges. This blocks an attack where a browser
          behind a firewall  is  used  to  probe  machines  on  the  local
          network.
```

You can disable this entirely by removing this option, or you can whitelist certain domains using this option:

```
--rebind-domain-ok=example.com
```

Comment: Thanks. Same problem as OP, using public DNS to store internal IPs. Couldn't understand why `dig -t ANY` would give me a proper `A` record, but plain `dig` (e.g. `dig -t A`) would give me nothing. Also couldn't understand why it only was an issue intermittently: it was only when I was connected to a network using dnsmasq.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be Bind9 view feature, especially if your DNSMasq is not in the same ip range as your PC

> The view statement is a powerful new feature of BIND 9 that lets a name server answer a DNS query differently depending on who is asking (...) [more](http://www.bind9.net/manual/bind/9.3.2/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2562349)